# Error when file is removed

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

```
import gc
import os

gc.disable()

open('tmp.txt', 'w').close()

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fo = open('tmp.txt')

a = A()

os.remove('tmp.txt')
```

When I execute the script, I got a `PermissionError: [WinError 32]`.Then I try this:

```
import gc
import os

gc.disable()

open('tmp.txt', 'w').close()

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fo = open('tmp.txt')

a = A()

# or a = None
del a

os.remove('tmp.txt')
```

Although it succeeded this time, but I don't know the reason. Could you tell me why?

My python version is 3.5.2.

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Comment: `class A` keeps an open handle to the file, so it's likely that the OS does not allow you to delete files that are open (which is the case on windows AFAIK)

Comment: PermissionError: [WinError 32]: windows all the way!

Comment: You should close the file before trying to remove it. Deleting `a` does it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on windows you cannot remove a file if some program has a handle on it.

When you deleted your instance, you manually/forcefully garbage collected the handle (since no other object had a reference on `a`), and closing the file, which explains that it worked.

also see [how to release used memory immediately in python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417498/how-to-release-used-memory-immediately-in-python-list/12417903#12417903) where it's explained that

```
del a
```

or

```
a = None
```

immediately frees the memory of `a` if no other object holds a reference on it.

Comment: I have called the  gc.disable to disable garbage collected, but it still works.I s my approach wrong?

Comment: but if you explicitly call `del`, the object is deleted even if garbage collector is not running. This is a manual garbage collection. Maybe I answered too fast. What do you want to achieve. Try `a=None` with gc off, you could have a different result.

Comment: when I assign None to `a` instead of `del` it, it still works. Is this a  garbage collection?

Comment: seems so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417498/how-to-release-used-memory-immediately-in-python-list/12417903#12417903

Comment: Specifically, on Windows you can't remove a file (i.e. set its delete disposition) unless all open instances share delete access. Python's `open` does not share delete access.