# Release memory after having deleted an element from a list

Tags: python, list, garbage-collection

When I try delete an element from python list the size of whole list is still the same.

```
import numpy as np
import sys

l = [np.arange(4) for i in range(4)]
print("size: {}".format(sys.getsizeof(l)))
index = 1
l[index] = None
del l[index]
print("size: {}".format(sys.getsizeof(l)))
```

show:

```
size: 96
size: 96
```

How to release memory after deleteing item?
`gc.collect()` does not work.

Comment: honestly, i wouldn't worry about it, it's almost certainly a micro-optimization, life is too short ;)

Comment: You'd have to re-create the list, e.g. `l=l[:]`, but the cost of re-allocation will times overweight the saved few bytes. Normally people are not supposed to care about those things when they code in Python, and even in C++ erasing a vector element does not change the allocated size.

Comment: Well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417498/how-to-release-used-memory-immediately-in-python-list)

Answer (score 1):

`list` is very cleverly implemented to allocate a small bit of over-allocation. So,

```
>>> l = []
>>> sys.getsizeof(l) 
# i have a 64-bit system. This value would have been different in a 32-bit,
# and this is basic memory required by the data structure itself. Over time the append happens,
# the memory will be increased on a bit more than required.  
# The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...
72
>>> l.append(1)
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
104
>>> l.append(2)
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
104
>>> l
[1, 2]
>>> for i in range(100):l.append(i)
... 
>>> l
[1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
920
```

So if you were to empty the `list`, you will get

```
>>> l[:] = []
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
72
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has built-in garbage collection and you don't have to manually release memory. Calling `del` on a list item removes that item from the list (same as the `pop` method when deleting a single index), but it offers no guarantees for actually freeing the underlying memory.

The reason why forcing a garbage collection with `gc.collect()` doesn't work is because the CPython list implementation tries to minimise the number of `malloc` and `free` calls overall, so in this case even after the element has been removed, they keep around the memory in case you'd assign a new element shortly after.